# ElasticSearch Missing definition for aggregation [unique_users] Error

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

> I am using ES with Ruby on Rails, I am in a situation where I have to
>   list all unique users so below is the code that I am using to get it.

```
    buckets['unique_users'] = {
      filter: { match_all: {} },
      aggregations: {
        users_count: {
          cardinality: {
            field: :customer_email_key
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

> and below is the response:

```
unique_users: {
  doc_count: 134,
    users_count: {
      value: 125
    }
  }
}
```

> This is only showing the number of unique users but this query does
>   not show the email listing so where is the issue in this query. Could
>   anyone guide me?

```
             ==========  New Edits  ==========
```

> Now I am using the code and its working fine with the users listing and it counts.

```
  def buckets_for_unique_users(buckets, aggregations)
    buckets['unique_users'] = {
      filter: { match_all: {} },
      aggregations: {
        users_count: {
          cardinality: {
            field: :customer_email_key
          }
        },
        details: {
          terms: {
            field: :customer_email_key,
            size: 200
          }
        }
      }
    }
  end
```

now getting above code response is:

```
unique_users: {
  doc_count: 134,
  users_count: {
   value: 125
  },
  details: {
    doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0,
    sum_other_doc_count: 0,
    buckets: [
      {
        key: "example@gmail.com",
        doc_count: 2
      }
      {....}
    ]
}
```

Now everything is going perfect but there is something in the response that is the little bit confusing so I have to remove that i.e the **doc_count: 134** because I want to keep **users_count** and remove **doc_count**. So for this what I did I removed **filter: { match_all: {} },** from the method and then I got error `Missing definition for aggregation [unique_users]`

Comment: could you show, how your code looks like without filter match_all

Comment: this is because your bucket is called details, right?

Comment: @Mysterion should I remove the name details from bucket?

Comment: @Mysterion This is code without filter match_all.
    `buckets['unique_users'] = {
      aggregations: {
        users_count: {
          cardinality: {
            field: :customer_email_key
          }
        },
        details: {
          terms: {
            field: :customer_email_key,
            size: 200
          }
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: i think yes - you need to rename

Comment: I have renamed it to "users" and again same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html):

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "users" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "customer_email_key" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mysterion thank you for your reply now the I am getting the perfect response but I am getting some new error after changing the code.

Comment: I have updated the question, Please see it, the error is **Missing definition for aggregation [unique_users] Error
**